# How can I run onChange or onEdit in Google Apps Script only when new data is entered on the sheet I want?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

i have 3 sheets my spreadsheet. Names is sheet1, sheet2, sheet3. And i have a function "onChange()". i install onChange function at triggers. i want run onChange function if only when add new row at sheet2 . But not working properly. if i write sheet1 or sheet2 or sheet3 anything always run my onChange function.

```
function onChange(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet2");
var sheet2lr = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(),1,1,2).getValues();
var sheet1lr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1");
sheet1lr.getRange(getLastRow(),1,1,4).setValues(sheet2lr)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to run the script of `onChange()` when new row is inserted to "sheet2".
- Your function of `onChange()` has already been installed as the OnChange installable trigger.

In this case, I thought that `changeType` and `source` of the event object can be used for achieving your goal. When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function onChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType != "INSERT_ROW" || e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() != "sheet2") return; // Added

  // do something
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet2"); // Or e.source.getSheetByName("sheet2");
  var sheet2lr = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 2).getValues();
  var sheet1lr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1"); // Or e.source.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  sheet1lr.getRange(getLastRow(), 1, 1, 4).setValues(sheet2lr)
}
```

- In this modified script, when new row is inserted to "sheet2", the script below the if statement is run.
- When you want to run this script, please insert new row to the sheet of "Sheet2".

#### Note:

- If above modified didn't work, please reinstall the OnChange trigger to the function `onChange`.
- For your script, I think that you can also the event object of `e.source` instead of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`.

#### Reference:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

### Added:

About your following comment,

> thanks Tanaike for help me.  if the user adds a row to sheet2, the onchange function works(only change equlas oparator != change ==).actually another application is adding a row to sheet2. when if i use 1 control `e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == "sheet2")` working but if i use second control not fire `onChange e.changeType != "INSERT_ROW".`

In the current stage, in your situation, OnChange trigger can be used when the row is manually inserted and the row is inserted with Sheets API which is not Google Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp). So from your comment, in your situation, I thought that the row is inserted with SpreadsheetApp. If my understanding is correct, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your current script of `onChange()` is called from the function of `actually another application is adding a row to sheet2`. When your script of `actually another application is adding a row to sheet2` is including in the same Google Apps Script project of `onChange()` and it supposes that the function name is `sample()`, you can modify as follows.

```
function sample() {
  // do something of `actually another application is adding a row to sheet2`
  
  onChange();
}

function onChange(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet2");
  var sheet2lr = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(),1,1,2).getValues();
  var sheet1lr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1");
  sheet1lr.getRange(getLastRow(),1,1,4).setValues(sheet2lr)
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the row is inserted with Sheets API in your script of `actually another application is adding a row to sheet2`. In this case, you can convert the script for inserting row using InsertDimensionRequest of the batchUpdate method. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#insertdimensionrequest) When this script is run, my proposed script can be used. Because when new row is inserted with Sheets API, the OnChange trigger is fired. In this case, I cannot understand about your script of `actually another application is adding a row to sheet2`. By this, I just propose the method for achieving your goal using Sheets API.

Comment: @Ahmet Hazin For your replying, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: At this stage, I think I will reach a solution with model 2. So I need to learn some information about sheet api.